# What coordinate format are these coordinates in?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I am looking at some old data, and I encountered a data point with a latitude and longitude coordinates in a format that I'm not familiar with. I tried researching some other formats and tried pinpointing the exact location with little luck.

example:

```
latitude: 484.196.111

longitude: 94.146.944
```

I am looking to convert such values to a suitable WGS84 format for mapping.

Comment: Can you add the map or a snapshot of the data?

Comment: Try to write the numbers with out the dots: 94146944. It can solved it

Comment: How would you interpret 94146944?

Comment: I need to see more of your data

Comment: it's literally value - latitude - longitude.

just trying to add a point of interest in a map, but the coordinates are not in the correct format.

Comment: In which country is the data supposed to be?

Comment: did you store these pois in excel? just asking because excel likes to be "intelligent" and converts formats without asking; thats where I sometimes get such coordinates from.

Comment: What about 48.4196112, 9.4146944

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem once, and writing the number without the dots solved it. 
Here the steps I used to solved the problem. I choose the "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator" CRS. This values does not exist in the  Mercator projection, I choose it because I have no data about regarding the right CRS.

1. save the numbers without the dots in a "CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) file. You can save any number of points that you need.

[image]

2. Upload the file as "Delimited Text Layer".

[image]

3. know you need to be sure that the X and Y fields are matching the latitude and longitude. Also, you need to choose the right CRS.
   [image]

In your case "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator" is not the right CRS, the point layer is nowhere to be found. 
Know, you  need to change the item CRS in the "layers" panel.

[image]

Inside this bar you can change the CRS and to see if you got the right CRRS. The red square should overlap the world map, which its CRS is "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator".

[image]

Know, if you have any data about the location which that data was created you can try with CRS that related to a country. Historically, there are a lot of CRS that were used by many different countries, so you have a lot of options. If you don't have this info you can always go over the CRS one by one.