# Convert X and Y values from an Israeli source to match the WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator CRS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have an Israeli database with  X and Y values that I need to upload into QGIS.

I have converted the Excel file into a CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) file and upload it as [Delimited Text Layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303375/what-coordinate-format-are-these-coordinates-in/303584#303584).

I have tried all the Israeli CRS listed in QGIS, and that data is still not matching.

[image]

It sure do look like the Israel outlines, but it is about 700kM off somewhere in the Egyptian desert.
[image]

What is needed in order to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem that I have figured it up, and the problem is quite an odd one.

The X and Y values are listed with a dot between the third and fifth numbers. In QGIS the CRS values are written without a dot, so obviously it cannot work like that.

[image]

Once I multiplied the numbers by 1,000 and uploaded the values as a whole number it fits the Israeli CRS.

[image]

Comment: It should be possible to eliminate the thousands separator dot inside Excel cell/number formatting before exporting. Or you can use a simple text editor like notepad++ to exchange all dots inside the csv to nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is related with the incompatibility of the *decimal separator* of your software, your system and maybe your data also. It is a quite common challenge, see [PEP-378](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/) and it deserve a lot of care to deal with it properly, specially if you are reading data from other

The *decimal separator* comes togheter with the *list separator*, *thousands separator* and other "cultural issues". I would say that in Qgis the dot as decimal separator is the best option becuase Python (and C) uses it internally and not all tools handle the local configuration in a good way.

Incompatible decimal separators is a pain we must learn to live with.