# Importing Several Latitude and longitude Points From a Smartphone App into a CSV File

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gps, android

I am using a GPS [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freemium.android.apps.gps.coordinates) on Android that export my location as a latitude and longitude values.

For each location it exporting a separate data set:

```
Latitude (LAT): 32.05796  
N 32°3'28.6578" 
Longitude (LONG): 34.83233  
E 34°49'56.39448"
```

It is quite easy to copy this data into a [CSV](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303593/convert-x-and-y-values-from-an-israeli-source-to-match-the-wgs-84-pseudo-merca) file and then to upload it into QGIS.

However, it is time consuming especially when I have 15 or more locations to add.

I have tried some [GPS apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=GPS) and they all doing pretty much the same thing.

Is there some App or a method that enables to collect several locations in one table?

Once the table is saved as CSV it should not be a problem to import it as CSV into QGIS.

Comment: Why not use the [Qfield](http://www.qfield.org/) app to digitize directly into layer?

Comment: here maps you can export your collections to csv or gpx waypoints. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.here.app.maps&hl=en_us

Comment: My OS is windows Pro 10

Comment: I would come up with a nice bash 1-liner if that would help.

Comment: Is this Google apps enable to import the data as a CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bash` solution:

Put all your data files in a subfolder named "data" and run this little script:

```bsh
{
# print some header
printf "%s,%s\n" LAT LON;
# print the data
grep -Pho '(LAT|LONG)\): \K.*' data/* | paste -d, - -
} > output.csv # redirect output between brackets to csv file
```

In one line for copy-paste:

```bsh
{ printf "%s,%s\n" LAT LON; grep -Pho '(LAT|LONG)\): \K.*' data/* | paste -d, - -; } > output.csv
```

You can [run `bash` on Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq).